# Timing inaccuracy in Haskell threadDelay

Tags: haskell, timing

I want to make rhythms with Haskell's printf. The following should produce a repeating rhythm in which one note is twice as long as the other two. (That rhythm is encoded by the list [1,1,2].)

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Text.Printf
import Control.Monad

main = mapM_ note (cycle [1,1,2])

beat = round (10^6 / 4) -- measured in miliseconds

note :: Int -> IO ()
note n = do
    threadDelay $ beat * n
    printf "\BEL\n"
```

When I run it the long note sounds roughly three times as long as the others, rather than twice. If I speed it up, by changing the number 4 to a 10, the rhythm is destroyed completely: the notes all have the same length.

Is there a refresh rate to change? Is threadDelay not the service to use if I want precise timing?

Comment: On the systems I'm familiar with, outputting a BEL blocks for a moment before the program continues, which will mess up your math.

Comment: @luqui: And on Windows it doesn't block, which messes up with your ears :/.

Comment: Why are you using `printf` instead of `print`?

Comment: Eventually I intend to send OSC messages to some other sound source; the print statement is just a stand-in for that. I don't know the difference between print and printf; that line just recycles some syntax from Simon Marlow's book on Concurrency ("reminders.hs", in Chapter 7).

Comment: Have you looked at the list of music libs on hackage? https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskore for example?

Answer (score 3):

> Is threadDelay not the service to use if I want precise timing?

No, [not at all](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#v:threadDelay):

> ```
> threadDelay :: Int -> IO () Source
> ```
>
> Suspends the current thread for a given number of microseconds (GHC only).
>
> **There is no guarantee that the thread will be rescheduled promptly when the delay has expired,** but the thread will never continue to run earlier than specified.

However, on my machine (Win 8.1 x64 i5-3570k@3.4GHz) the rhythm runs fine. That being said,  `\BEL` isn't really a good way to create a beat:

1. the `\BEL` sound depends on the operating system (sound dreadful in Windows 8 if played at that frequency),
2. it isn't clear whether `\BEL` blocks.

If the latter happens you end up with roughly the same length, since every `\BEL` will block and the `threadDelay` is shorter than the actual `\BEL` sound.

Comment: This answer would be much more helpful if it suggested some better ways.

Comment: @luqui: I'm not really familiar with the whole "create music with code" stuff (yet), sorry :(. If you know something about it, feel free to edit this answer (community wiki now) or provide a new answer :).

Answer (score 3):

The problem appears to have been print, not threading. Rohan Drape at Haskell-Cafe showed me how to use OSC instead of print. The timing of the following test, which uses OSC, is to my ears indistinguishable from perfect. I had it send instructions to a sine wave oscillator in Max/MSP.

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad
import System.IO
import Sound.OSC

main = do
    hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
    mapM_ note (cycle [1,1,2])

withMax = withTransport (openUDP "127.0.0.1" 9000)
beat = 60000 -- 60 ms, measured in µs

note :: Int -> IO ()
note n = do
    withMax (sendMessage (Message "sin0 frq 100" []))
        -- set sine wave 0 to frequency 100
    withMax (sendMessage (Message "sin0 amp 1" []))
        -- set sine wave 0 to amplitude 1
    threadDelay $ beat * n
    withMax (sendMessage (Message "sin0 amp 0" []))
        -- set sine wave 0 to amplitude 0
    threadDelay $ beat * n
```

Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you will have to rely on OS support or GHC internals. For example, I have used [GHC.Event](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.7.0.1/GHC-Event.html) for this purpose with the

```
registerTimeout :: TimerManager -> Int -> TimeoutCallback -> IO TimeoutKey
```

funtion. But then it will also be asynchronous with callbacks. Also this is GHC specific.

Other options are timer libraries on [hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/search?terms=timer), not sure though if they are all portable or if they can be used on Windows, but most use OS support as for precise timing you need hardware timers.